# owl carousel not working in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

i've problem with owl carousel in wordpress theme.
owl carousel works correctly in static page. but when i turn my page to wordpress theme , the images(carousel) have disappear.

here are my try in static mode (owl carousel works fine):

added libraries:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome-animation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/countUp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flowtype.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mk_theme.js"></script>
```

Html:

```
<!-- Links -->   
 <div class="links">
            <div class="container">
        <div id="links-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="links" src="img/links/01.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="links" src="img/links/02.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="links" src="img/links/03.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="links" src="img/links/04.png"></a>
                </div>



        </div>
        </div>
 </div>

 <!-- End Links -->
```

js(mk_theme.js):

```
var owl = $("#links-carousel");

  owl.owlCarousel({

      itemsCustom : [

        [450, 2],
        [700, 3],
        [1600, 4]
      ],
      navigation : false

  });
```

---

I turned my static page to wordpress theme:

added libraries in function.php

```
function mes_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css', array(), '1.3.3' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.3.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.4' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-rtl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css', array(), '3.3.2' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome-animation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome-animation.css', array(), '0.0.7' );



    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-1.11.2.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js', array(), '1.11.2' , true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array(), false , true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.min.js', array(), '1.3', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.4' , true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'countUp', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/countUp.min.js', array() , false , true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'flowtype', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/flowtype.js', array(), '1.1' , true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'mk-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mk_theme.js', array() , false , true );



}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mes_scripts' );
```

index.php:

```
<!-- Links -->   
 <div class="links">
            <div class="container">
        <div id="links-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="links" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/links/01.png' ?>"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="links" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/links/02.png' ?>"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="links" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/links/03.png' ?>"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a href="#"><img alt="links" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/links/04.png' ?>"></a>
                </div>



        </div>
        </div>
 </div>

 <!-- End Links -->
```

and i didn't change js codes in wordpress theme(mk_theme.js)

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: no, there is no error in there.

Comment: check the source if it's loading another version of jquery (maybe requested by a plugin) and try using the [jquery provided by wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery) rather than the one included in your theme

Answer (score 0):

check out your codes for any errors(in google chrome use Ctrl + Shift + I).
also in some cases it will be work on change "owl-carousel" to another version.

> for example if you use version 1.3.2 change it to version 2.0 beta.